# Where does websocket for python store it's received data

Tags: python-3.x, websocket

So I am coding a messenger and I want the code to react to certain messages but for that I need my code to see the received data. (I'm coding on windows):
Everything works perfectly but I don't know where the received data is stored or if you had to add something.

The best thing would be a list in which it stores it.

```
def get(s, new_window=None):
    while True:
        tm = s.recv(1024)
        print("\nReceived: ",tm.decode('ascii'))
        A.append(tm.decode('ascii'))
        if A == "RickRoll":
            print("Success")
        print("Enter: ")
        if tm == "RickRoll":
            print("It works")

def set_(s):
    while True:
        i=input("Enter : ")
        s.send(i.encode('ascii'))

serversocket = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 9981
serversocket.bind((host,port))
serversocket.listen(1)
clientsocket,addr = serversocket.accept()
t1=threading.Thread( target = get ,  args = (clientsocket,) )
t1.start()
t2=threading.Thread( target = set_ ,  args = (clientsocket,) )
t2.start()
```

do I have to add code like

```
A.append(tm.decode('ascii'))
        if A == "RickRoll":
            print("Success")
        print("Enter: ")
        if tm == "RickRoll":
            print("It works")
```

Is there a way to do this. The above solution doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to use the tm variable:

```
tm = s.recv(1024)
```

I would suggest appending tm to a self made variable and then use that